# Would someone please share a current SpriteKit texture atlas sample to pull apart

Tags: animation, sprite-kit, textures

My background is Arduino and I have found Swift a bit opaque. There are a lot of outdated tutorials out there too. I am working on just getting an animated sprite on screen. I have a small animated .png sequence that I will use, saving it into a ball.atlas folder and copying it to Assets.xcassets.

I have found what I believe was posted by Knight0fDragon. Running it shows "worked" in the console, but I don't understand how to assign it to a player so to speak and thus show up on the simulator. If someone would be willing to share the additional code needed to do so, I could pull it apart.

Here is the code:

```
    let textureAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "example")
    var textureArray = [SKTexture]()
    var frames:[SKTexture] = []
    for index in 1 ... 59 {
        let textureName = "example_\(index)"
        let texture = textureAtlas.textureNamed(textureName)
        frames.append(texture)
        textureArray = frames
        print("worked")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't share a texture atlas with you but I help explain a little see below

```
let textureAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "example")
var textureArray = [SKTexture]()
var frames:[SKTexture] = []
for index in 1 ... 59 {
    let textureName = "example_\(index)" 
    let texture = textureAtlas.textureNamed(textureName)
    frames.append(texture)
    textureArray = frames
    print("worked")
```

The line that gives "let textureName = "example_(index)" is where KoD gives you the naming convention for all the sprites in the Atlas. The atlas itself for this bit of code is called "example". All the sprites saved in the Atlas are assigned the following name "example_X" (X is an integer). example_1, example_2, example_3 etc... etc until you get to example_59. If you don't want to make 59 textures then you need to edit the for loop giving the new value.

hmmmmm OK have a look here

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene{

//MARK: PROPERTIES
var lastUpdateTime: TimeInterval = 0
var dt: TimeInterval = 0
var myAnimation = SKAction()
let myAnimaTimeInterval: TimeInterval = 0.1
let mySprite = SKSpriteNode(texture: SKTextureAtlas(named: "example").textureNamed("example_1"))

//MARK: INITIALISATION
override func sceneDidLoad() {

}

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    addChild(mySprite)
    mySprite.position = CGPoint.zero
    setAnimation()
    runAnimation(node: mySprite)
}

//MARK: GAME LOOP
override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    updateGameLoopTimer(currentTime: currentTime)

}

override func didEvaluateActions() {

}

override func didFinishUpdate() {

}

//MARK: TOUCHES
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

}

//MARK: HELPER FUNCTIONS
private func setAnimation() {
    let textureAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "example")
    var textureArray: [SKTexture] = []
    for index in 2...59 {
        let textureName = "example_\(index)"
        let texture = textureAtlas.textureNamed(textureName)
        textureArray.append(texture)
    }
    for index in (1...58).reversed() {
        let textureName = "example_\(index)"
        let texture = textureAtlas.textureNamed(textureName)
        textureArray.append(texture)
    }

    let animation = SKAction.animate(with: textureArray, timePerFrame: myAnimaTimeInterval)
    myAnimation = SKAction.repeatForever(animation)
}

private func runAnimation(node: SKSpriteNode) {
    node.run(myAnimation, withKey: "myAnimation")
}

private func stopAnimation(node: SKSpriteNode) {
    node.removeAction(forKey: "myAnimation")
}

public func updateGameLoopTimer(currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    if lastUpdateTime > 0 {
        dt = currentTime - lastUpdateTime
    } else {
        dt = 0
    }
    lastUpdateTime = currentTime
}


//MARK: CLEAN-UP
deinit {

}
}
```

I've taken a few liberties with the first sprite for the character which made me change the loop a little.

You can attach the animation to any sprite using the runAnimation method and stop the animation with the stopAnimation method. I've just added the animation to the didMoveToView call.

Try replacing your gameScene file with the above. OK now with the game loop timer ... maybe there are better ways to time the game.... but for you and me it is OK.

Try it again

Comment: Thank you hoboBob, I appreciate the answer. I understand what you are saying. My atlas is indeed called "example.atlas" and it has 59 sequentially numbered .png files in it. I don't know the remaining code to actually make my animated sprite appear onscreen. For example, where does this code block reside, in the override func didMove(to view: SKView) {here?} then I add child?

Comment: Hmmm OK have another look ? any better ?

Comment: Like a flashlight hoboBob, I can see a lot more logic now. Two questions if you please: 1. for "updateGameLoopTimer(currentTime): currentTime) I get an unresolved identifier error. 2. one thing I didn't expect is that it we assign the one first .png image to the my sprite, then in the helper functions, assign the animation so to speak. Would you please comment on that? Thank you.

Comment: ahhh sorry dude my bad I used a boiler plate. The "updateGameLoopTimer" Is a nice method for timing things inside the game loop. Probably better ways but its good for our level. I've updates the answer. Keep it as a method and make your own boiler plate. With the animations.... all I know  is you have a picture.. and you have 1...to....59 of these. Soooo I took some liberties when choosing what sprite to start and the loop to make the animation. Look try again you should see all the images in your sprite atlas loop continuously .

Comment: Brilliant, this example makes sense to me, not so alien from the Arduino anymore.  Now I have a base of understanding.Thank you hoboBob.

Comment: its kinda the norm to upmark the answer and tick. But sure no problem

Comment: Thanks again hoboBob I tried upmark but I don't have the user level yet to do so, I get a dialog box when trying to. As for the tick this was my first question so I didn't know I was allowed to tick either. Thanks though for letting me know and for answering in the first place. Cheers.